# How do I restrict use of a computer to one domain user only on Active Diredctory?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

Today I am looking for a new trick, it's how do I How do I restrict use of a computer to one domain user only on Active Diredctory?

I want an only user to Login on a machine and nobody else from the same Domain can login to this Machine .
I wanna apply this Tricks in my Company all of Computers, I found a trick how to specify a user to open his session on computer .

This is the Trick that I found:

> https://4sysops.com/archives/deny-and-allow-workstation-logons-with-group-policy/

But not I am looking for something to apply on the Active Directory Server.
It's better if I can use GPOs.

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do this through GPO and not sure why you would want to do this for every user in the domain, but I would suggest that you specify on the user properties for every user where they can logon and provide for every user another computer name,  see here - [User Properties - Account Tab](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145547.aspx).